# ¿Cómo implemento una base de datos a una app echa con electron?

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, electron

Estoy creando una app con electrón, y estoy utilizando XAMPP como servidor local para la base de datos, pero no encuentro como  hacer para que una vez que termine la app y cree el instalador ya no ocupe XAMPP para la base de datos, si no que al momento que se instale el programa ya pueda hacer uso de la app y pueda guardar la información

Comment: hay varias opciones https://rxdb.info/electron-database.html o algún db2json https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-db . SQLite suele ser lo mas aconsejable si luego planeas usar lenguages o frameworks que compilen a bytecode nativo, sobre todo si no hay que tener conexion para usar la app

Answer (score 0):

Según mi parecer, no sería la mejor práctica hacerlo de esa manera.
Lo que mejor te conviene es crear un backend aparte con una base de datos y hacer la conexión con el servidor por medio de un endpoint rest.

Ya que veo que usas electrón podrías armar tu servidor en node y express con algún ORM de base de datos como sequelize o typeorm.

Ejemplo de servidor y endpoint

```js
// Importar Express.js
const express = require('express');

// Crear una instancia de la aplicación
const app = express();

// Definir una ruta para la solicitud GET
app.get('/getData', (req, res) => {
  res.json({data: 'Mandar data aquí'})
});

// Iniciar el servidor en el puerto 3000
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('La aplicación está funcionando en el puerto 3000');
});
```

La lógica de la base de datos la tendrías que meter en el backend y listo y con hacer una request a "[host]/getData" ya obtendrías toda la funcionalidad.